# Uncaught RangeError: noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add few sliders on website and I got stucked. I've downloaded nouislider script directly from their website and before that, I added jQuery 1.8.0 to my website. This is what I produced:

*index.html*

```
<head>
   ...
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/noUiSlider/jquery.nouislider.css" type="text/css">
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery.nouislider.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/website.js"></script>
   ...
</head>
<body>
   ...
   <div id="sslider" class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-background"></div>
   ...
</body>
```

*website.js*

```
(function () {
   $("#sslider").noUiSlider({
       start: 5,
       range: {
           'min': 1,
           'max': 80
       }
   });
})();
```

When I debug in Chrome, I' catching exactly this:
[image: Exception]

Can you help me?

Comment: I will suggest you to use [document-ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead of IIFE

Comment: @oGeez - there is no more information about this error in text. You can click on image and select Open Image ... (or something like that).

Comment: @Satpal - I've tried to do that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `jquery.nouislider.js` getting loaded? Are you getting any console error?

Comment: As you can see in error screen, there is:
`Invalid noUiSlider initialisation:
Option:  range 
Value:  Object {min: 1, max: 80}
Slider(s):  
[div#sslider.noUi-target.noUi-ltr.noUi-horizontal.noUi-background, context: document, selector: "#sslider", constructor: function, init: function, jquery: "1.8.0"…]
0: div#sslider.noUi-target.noUi-ltr.noUi-horizontal.noUi-background
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#sslider"
__proto__: Object[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I have downloaded jquery.nouislider.js from NuGet (from VisualStudio 2013) and they provided me older or broken file. I thought the file was from website, but I browsed NuGet and noticed, that I have already downloaded from there.

There is no problem with code but with file. Lesson: before asking question, compare official files with those you already have installed.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your example into a test file, and it works fine. I also can't see how the error message in your example could be generated by the current version of noUiSlider, so I'd suggest using the latest version of noUiSlider and the latest version of jQuery.

It would also be a good idea to only run this JS after the page has loaded, [like this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
    $("#sslider").noUiSlider({
        start: 5,
        range: {
            'min': 1,
            'max': 80
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the **[official docs](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/)**:

```
$("#slider").noUiSlider({
    start: [5],
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min': 1,
        'max': 80
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't help. I copied few examples from their docs, but none were working.

Comment: 100%. Chrome doesn't fire Resource Not Found and I check every file by hand and it seems, I loaded all necessery files.